# Chart.js Doughnut with rounded with Vue3 and vue-chart-3

Tags: vue.js, charts

I want to create a donut graphic with rounded arcs. I can't seem to separate the start and end arcs from changing arcs from my sections of the graph. I have this :

I can't find how to modify arc of my sections of the chart. I have this:[image]

I want it to look like this: [image]

```
    /* In parents */
    // template
            <DoughnutChart class="simulator__doughnut" :chartData="datacollection"/>
    // computed
        datacollection() {
            return {
                datasets: [
                    {
                        data: [this.monthlyPayment, this.monthlyRate],
                        backgroundColor: ["#ff0058", "#ff645a"],
                        borderWidth: 0,
                        angle: [50],
                        borderRadius: [{ innerEnd: 50, outerEnd: 50 }],
                    },
                ],
            };
        },
```

```
/* In Children*/
<script>
import { DoughnutController, Chart } from "chart.js";

Chart.register(DoughnutController);

export default {
    extends: DoughnutController,
    mixins: [reactiveProp],
    mounted() {
        this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.chartOptions);
    },
    props: {
        chartData: {
            type: Object,
            default: null,
        },
        chartOptions: {
            type: Object,
            default: null,
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* In parents */
// template
        <DoughnutChart class="simulator__doughnut" :chartData="datacollection"/>
// computed
    datacollection() {
        return {
            datasets: [
                {
                    data: [this.monthlyPayment, this.monthlyRate],
                    backgroundColor: ["#ff0058", "#ff645a"],
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    angle: [50],
                    borderRadius: [{ innerEnd: 50, outerEnd: 50, innerStart: 50, outerStart: 50}],
                    spacing: -50
                },
            ],
        };
    },
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).